# Is there a way of labelling data sequentially in python by group?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataset grouped by an ID, but I want to add a new label according to the date the ID occurred.

My dataset looks like this:

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10/11/20 |
| 1 | 15/11/20 |
| 1 | 13/12/20 |
| 1 | 16/12/20 |
| 2 | 10/11/19 |
| 2 | 15/11/19 |
| 2 | 13/12/20 |
| 2 | 16/12/20 |
| 3 | 10/11/19 |
| 3 | 15/11/19 |
| 3 | 13/12/20 |
| 3 | 16/12/20 |
| 4 | 10/11/19 |
| 4 | 15/11/19 |
| 4 | 13/12/20 |
| 4 | 16/12/20 |

And so on.

I would like my dataset, when ordered, to then look like this:

| ID | Date | Order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10/11/20 | 1 |
| 1 | 15/11/20 | 2 |
| 1 | 13/12/20 | 3 |
| 1 | 16/12/20 | 4 |
| 2 | 10/11/19 | 1 |
| 2 | 15/11/19 | 2 |
| 2 | 13/12/20 | 3 |
| 2 | 16/12/20 | 4 |
| 3 | 10/11/19 | 1 |
| 3 | 15/11/19 | 2 |
| 3 | 13/12/20 | 3 |
| 3 | 16/12/20 | 4 |
| 4 | 10/11/19 | 1 |
| 4 | 15/11/19 | 2 |
| 4 | 13/12/20 | 3 |
| 4 | 16/12/20 | 4 |

Does anybody know if there is a way to do this or a function that could help?

Comment: `df.groupby('id')['Date'].rank()`? `df.groupby('id').cumcount() + 1 ` would also work if data is sorted.

Comment: In Pandas these are "windowing operations" ( similar to SQL window functions). Pandas can only do it with numeric types so you have to create a date index first. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53433242/pandas-dataframe-window-using-date-index and https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/window.html